# Is GDB aware of C# code compiled in debug mode (.pdb / .mdb files)

Tags: c#, debugging, msbuild, mono, gdb

I'm debugging a C# application running on mono run-time. Compiling it w/ `msbuild X.sln '/p:Configuration=Debug'` or w/ `msbuild X.sln '/p:Configuration=Release'` gives me the same stack trace in gdb (this is the same read() call):

```
Thread 1 (Thread 0x7f37f8ebd720 (LWP 16269)):
#0  0x00007f37f840a82d in read () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:82
#1  0x00000000005f956d in console_read (handle=0x0, buffer=0x7f37f13d0db8, numbytes=1024, bytesread=0x7fff748848c4) at w32file-unix.c:1903
#2  0x00000000005fb87c in mono_w32file_read (handle=0x0, buffer=0x7f37f13d0db8, numbytes=1024, bytesread=0x7fff748848c4) at w32file-unix.c:3109
#3  0x00000000007561e0 in ves_icall_System_IO_MonoIO_Read (handle=0x0, dest=0x7f37f13d0d98, dest_offset=0, count=1024, error=0x7fff74884a10) at w32file.c:866
#4  0x00000000403066fa in ?? ()
#5  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()


Thread 1 (Thread 0x7fa729652720 (LWP 610)):
#0  0x00007fa728b9f82d in read () at ../sysdeps/unix/syscall-template.S:82
#1  0x00000000005f956d in console_read (handle=0x0, buffer=0x7fa71d940580, numbytes=1024, bytesread=0x7fff6b7bd784) at w32file-unix.c:1903
#2  0x00000000005fb87c in mono_w32file_read (handle=0x0, buffer=0x7fa71d940580, numbytes=1024, bytesread=0x7fff6b7bd784) at w32file-unix.c:3109
#3  0x00000000007561e0 in ves_icall_System_IO_MonoIO_Read (handle=0x0, dest=0x7fa71d940560, dest_offset=0, count=1024, error=0x7fff6b7bd8d0) at w32file.c:866
#4  0x0000000041b396fa in ?? ()
#5  0x0000000000000000 in ?? ()
```

**Question:** does it make any difference in general for GDB when debugging a C# application compiled in debug mode? And if it does / does not - how (it would be interesting to see how GDB operates with .pdb / .mdb files for example)?

Comment: Mono works with different format of symbol files (.mdb, not .pdb)

Comment: Thanks, added .mdb files as well. Although the meaning of the question does not change much it is useful for me to know as a freshmen in mono runtime.

Comment: I have asked mono developer in their gitter - mono now supports both pdb and gdb.

Comment: Thanks, good to know.

Comment: http://www.mono-project.com/docs/debug+profile/debug/#debugging-with-gdb